# Taylor Series Expansion of unknown, fraction function

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, differentiation, calculus

I am learning about deformation, and the deformed state between two points can be defined as
$$E(x) = \frac{(f(x+dx) - f(x))^2 - (dx)^2}{2(dx)^2}$$
My textbook says

> When $dx \to 0$ we can use a Taylor Series Expansion to find
> $$E(x) = \frac{f'(x)^2 - 1}{2} $$

I have absolutely no idea how they came to this solution. How do you take the Taylor series of something like $E(x)$? I understand the Taylor series approximation, but I have no idea how it can be applied to an unknown mapping like this. Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: While the below answer is a correct way to think, you can also do as the text states by taylor expanding $f(x+dx)$ about the point $x$ (in other words as $dx\to 0$). Then $f(x+dx)= f(x) + f'(x)dx + \frac12 f''(x) (dx)^2+\dots$, then it's straightforward to get the same result as the text.

Answer (score 5):

Without making use of Taylor series what the textbook is computing is
\begin{align}
E(x)
&= \lim_{dx\to0} \frac{(f(x+dx)-f(x))^2-(dx)^2}{2(dx)^2} \\
&= \frac12\lim_{dx\to0} \left(\left(\frac{f(x+dx)-f(x)}{dx}\right)^2-\frac{(dx)^2}{(dx)^2}\right) \\
&= \frac12\left(\left(\lim_{dx\to0} \frac{f(x+dx)-f(x)}{dx}\right)^2-\lim_{dx\to0}\frac{(dx)^2}{(dx)^2}\right) \\
&= \frac{f'(x)^2-1}{2}
\end{align}

Alternatively if you want to use Taylor series, recall that up to higher $dx$ powers
$$
f(x+dx)-f(x) = f'(x)dx + \dots
$$
so that
$$
\begin{align}
E(x)
&= \frac{(f(x+dx)-f(x))^2-(dx)^2}{2(dx)^2} \\
&= \frac{(f'(x)dx)^2-(dx)^2}{2(dx)^2} + \dots \\
&= \frac{f'(x)^2-1}{2} + \dots
\end{align}
$$
where omitted terms go to zero when $dx\to0$

Answer (score 2):

This is not the Taylor series expansion for E(x).  The derivation uses the Taylor series expansion for f(x) to determine the strain in the material at material location x.

f(x) is the location at time t of the material point that was at location x at time zero.  The focus of this analysis is the small element of material that was situated between locations x and x + dx at time zero.  At time t, this same element of material is situated between location f(x) and f(x+dx).  Using a Taylor series expansion for f(x), the length of this same element of material at time t is f'(x)dx.  So the square of the length is $(f'(x))^2(dx)^2$ at time t, and the initial length was $(dx)^2$.  So the square of the stretch ratio $\lambda(x)$ is $$\lambda^2(x)=\frac{(f'(x))^2(dx)^2}{(dx)^2}=(f'(x))^2$$ The strain in the material element length is defined as $$E(x)=\frac{\lambda^2(x)-1}{2}=\frac{(f'(x))^2-1}{2}$$